# Get random line from url with requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I need my program to go to a url (url has only plain text on it) and I want it to get a random line from the url. I can't seem to get it to work.

This is what you get when you visit the url:

```
opulence
sumptuousness
elegant
lavishness
sumptuosity
luxuriousness
affluence
hotel
boutique
villas
interiors
sedans
amenities
furnishings
condo
automobiles
frills
fancy
mansions
leisure
condominium
dining
```

This is my code:

```
import random, requests

amount = int(input("Amount of lines to get?: "))
shopping_begin = requests.get("URL")

def generate_dork():
    for x in range(amount):
        for line in shopping_begin.text:
            return "".join([random.choice(line)])
```

Expected output: Random lines from the url to be printed for the amount of the amount `int(input))`

Output: `o` (when I put `20` in for `amount`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to return here

```
return "".join([random.choice(line)])
```

You grab an item and the function returns already. Instead do something like

```
def generate_dork():
   list = []
   for x in range(amount):
       for line in shopping_begin.text:
           list += [random.choice(line)]
   return list
```

To return a string probably something like this would do

```
def generate_dork():
   list = []
   for x in range(amount):
       for line in shopping_begin.text:
           list += [random.choice(line)]
   return " ".join(list)
```

Comment: What'd I do if I just wanted them in plaintext (not in a list)

Comment: @victorbrowser is this what you mean? see modified code.

Comment: Why was this upvoted/accepted? Unless I'm missing something, it's just going to return the empty string every time

Comment: @covfefe19 This only includes the algorithm for returning the string. He has no issue reading the data for shopping_begin. only his generate_dork was not working as expected.

Comment: But it put `s = ""` and then you never re-assign `s` to anything else before returning it

Answer (score 0):

You **should** use [`random.choices`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_random_choices.asp) rather than [`random.choice`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_random_choice.asp).

For example, if you have a text like this :

```
opulence
sumptuousness
elegant
lavishness
sumptuosity
luxuriousness
affluence
hotel
boutique
```

And you have an amount.

You can use [`random.choices`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_random_choices.asp) to get N random choice into a list from a list :

```py
import random

random_choices_list = random.choices([line for line in shopping_begin.text], k=amount)
```

Then you can convert the list to string if you want to keep it as text not as a python list :

```py
# you can specify the separator 
text_plan = " ".join(random_choices_list) # white space separator
text_plan = ",".join(random_choices_list) # comma separator
text_plan = "\n".join(random_choices_list) # new line separator
```